# Error CORS Laravel -- Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angular, laravel, cors

I have developed a rest Laravel API with Angular.

- Laravel: -> 5.7 *
- Angular: -> 8.2.9
- __________Angular CLI: 8.3.8

The project is separated by 2 folders each with its different technology.

Once the project is finished, move it to production with the IONOS server.

But I got this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.alfarim.es/category' from origin 'http://www.alfarim.es' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
app.component.ts:63 

HttpErrorResponse

api.alfarim.es/category:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

### 1st - Create a Subdomain

1. I uploaded the Laravel project to a folder
2. Create a Subdomain in IONOS
3. Create the subdomain that points to the Laravel public folder
4. Modify Angular's global variable to match Subdomain.

### 2nd - Middleware

// We create a middleware

```
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*’)
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS’);
```

// we enter the Kernel

```
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

// Add to routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(){
    //rutes
});
```

And then doing all the settings

Link: https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

### 3rd - Fruitcake

Installing

```
composer require fruitcake / laravel-cors
```

And then doing all the settings

Link: https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

---

### Actual state

**Middleware**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*’)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS’);

    }
}
```

**Kernel**

```
protected $middleware = [
      ....
      \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class, 
    ];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
        .....
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

**cors.php --- config**

```
    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    /*
    * Matches the request method. `[*]` allows all methods.
    */
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Matches the request origin. `[*]` allows all origins.
     */
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Matches the request origin with, similar to `Request::is()`
     */
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header. `[*]` allows all headers.
     */
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header with these headers.
     */
    'exposed_headers' => [],

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age response header when > 0.
     */
    'max_age' => 0,

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
     */
    'supports_credentials' => false,

    $app->configure('cors');
];
```

**Routes**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(){
    //.....
    Route::post('/api/register/','UserController@register');
    });
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. If Chrome doesn’t show it, use devtools in Firefox instead. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Answer (score -3):

Usually, you have to setup your server to accept the Corss.
try to edit your aache configuration (in your httpd.conf or within a .htaccess file) in this way

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

to ensure that your configuration is right, use

apachectl -t

and then restart apache